# Is there a different approach in CSS instead of using expression?

Tags: css, html, meta

Below image will give you more understanding of what I'm asking about.
[image: Image.]
I need different approach  instead of or is there a way in using CSSexpression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop) on a DOCType html while converting to IE9 from IE11?
Heres my code

```
     %@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Test.aspx.vb" Inherits="Test" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<%--<!DOCTYPE html>--%>(If uncomment this, error in expression)
<html>
```

Converting IE9

```
   <head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
   <title ></title>
```

Expression method in IE9

```
<style type="text/css">
  .mydatagrid
{
    /*width: 50%;*/
    border: solid 2px #333a56;
    /*min-width: 50%;*/
    margin: 0px 10px;
}

.header
{
    background-color: #333a56;
    font-family: Calibri;
    color: White;
    border: none 0px transparent;
    height: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    position:absolute  ;
    top:expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);
    z-index: 2;
    margin-left: -2px;
    margin-top:-1px;

}

.rows
{ 
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000;
    min-height: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    border: solid 1px #333a56;
    height:12px;
}

</style>

</head> 
    <body>
```

Gridview

```
   <div  id="Div1" runat="server"  style="width: 50%;margin:10px;overflow:auto; height :150px ">


            <asp:GridView ID="dgv_WorkOrder" runat="server"  CssClass="mydatagrid" EnableModelValidation="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" PagerStyle-CssClass="pager" RowStyle-CssClass="rows" RowStyle-Wrap ="true" SelectedRowStyle-CssClass="selectedrow"   EmptyDataText="No Records Selected" AllowPaging="False"  width="100%"    >
                   <Columns>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" ButtonType="Image" SelectImageUrl="~/Resources/icon_Select.png" ItemStyle-Width="20px">
                            <ControlStyle Width="20px"></ControlStyle>
                            <ItemStyle Width="20px"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:CommandField>

                        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" DeleteImageUrl="~/Resources/icon_X.png" ShowDeleteButton="True" ItemStyle-Width="20px">

                            <ItemStyle Width="20px"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:CommandField>

                    </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
</div>





        </form>


</body>

</html>
```

End of the Code

Comment: I believe if you give the parent of the header `position:relative`, then just `top:0` will do.

Comment: But to answer the more general question: no, you don't have access to JavaScript properties from within CSS. That is a legacy-IE-only thing.

Comment: No, I've recently tried and It wont do.

Comment: do we have different approach on this?